# cellForRowAtIndexPath is executing before the source is getting data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("loaded hie \(accountId)")
    let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("SELECT Name,Id FROM Account where parentid='\(self.accountId)'");
    //SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: self);
    SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: {error in print(error)}, completeBlock: { responce in print(responce)
        self.dataRows = responce["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
        var counter = 0;
        for i in self.dataRows
        {
            let requestForGrandChilds = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("select Name,Id from Account where parentid='\(i["Id"]!)'")
            SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(requestForGrandChilds,
            failBlock:
            {
                error in print(error)
                print("error block")
            },
            completeBlock:
            {
                responceChild in
                self.grandChilds = responceChild["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
                print(self.grandChilds)
                self.dataOfGrandChilds["\(counter)"] = self.grandChilds
                print(self.dataOfGrandChilds)
                counter += 1

                //Reloading My tableView
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    })
}
```

This is my `viewDidLoad()`.
Here `dataOfGrandChilds` is a dictionary which is source for my table view's cells.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("toViewChilds", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    print("loading content\(self.dataOfGrandChilds)")
    if let tempData = dataOfGrandChilds[indexPath.section]
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = tempData[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String
    }
    return cell
}
```

This is My `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

The problem is before the `dataForGrandChilds` is holding the content in `viewDidLoad()`,`cellForRowAtIndexPath()` is executing.That's why i could not populate the values of `dataForGrandChilds`. Please give me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to reload your table view

`yourTableView.reloadData()`

Put this code after your web request did finish with data.

You can add it for example at the end of your `completeBlock:`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("loaded hie \(accountId)")
    let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("SELECT Name,Id FROM Account where parentid='\(self.accountId)'");
    //SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: self);
    SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: {error in print(error)}, completeBlock: { responce in print(responce)
        self.dataRows = responce["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
        var counter = 0;
        for i in self.dataRows
        {
            let requestForGrandChilds = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("select Name,Id from Account where parentid='\(i["Id"]!)'")
            SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(requestForGrandChilds,
            failBlock:
            {
                error in print(error)
                print("error block")
            },
            completeBlock:
            {
                responceChild in
                self.grandChilds = responceChild["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
                print(self.grandChilds)
                self.dataOfGrandChilds["\(counter)"] = self.grandChilds
                print(self.dataOfGrandChilds)
                counter += 1

                //RELOAD TABLE VIEW HERE
                yourTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: @RamcharanReddy reload data in main thread `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}`

Comment: No, not at the end of `viewDidLoad`, at the end of your web request ;) Please see updated code snippet @RamcharanReddy

Comment: Now I tried. No result. @EvgenyKarkan

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.tableView.reloadData() }
That also i have tried. No Result.

Comment: Check your data source array - is it exists, is it empty or not?

Comment: I'm able to print the content of my data source array @EvgenyKarkan
That u can c in the above code

Comment: So, your `dataOfGrandChilds` array and `tempData` array are not empty, right? Check also `tempData[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String` for nil or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Assign an empty array to self.dataOfGrandChilds
2. add a reloadData at the end of the completeBlock so the

Result:
Tableview will load fine with 0 cells and refreshes will all data when the data is there.

Comment: Did the same thing but reloading is not working actually @Helge Becker

Answer (score 1):

Reload your tableview in your completion block from where you are printing your response or where your for loop ends. Something like,

```
  tableView.reloadData()
```

And make sure that you `tempData` and `tempData[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String` is not nil. check it by putting `print` statement or by putting `breakpoints`.

Comment: I have tried putting the  ' tableView.reloadData() ' at the last line of my loop as above. But it is not working. @Lion

Comment: Have you checkk your data ? `tempData`, `dataOfGrandChilds`, `self.dataRows` etc????  and you are fetching data like `if let tempData = dataOfGrandChilds[indexPath.section]` so are you sure that it is `indexPath.section` not `indexPath.row` ??

Comment: Yea yea @Lion... I'm pretty sure about that thing. I'm using section number as the key for particular array . dataOfGrandChilds is the dictionary that is having section number as key and corresponding as child. I tried putting breakpoints and print statements also.

Comment: I tried like this
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue,{ self.tableView.reloadData})

Still I did not get it.@Lion

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        
            self.tableView.reloadData
        
        } It should be like this i think for swift!

Comment: Actually both are same in swift. Even tried that way also . :(  @Lion

Comment: put breakpoint on `cell.textLabel?.text = tempData[indexPath.row]["Name"] as? String` this line and check have your debugger reaches here ? and if yes then what is the string at that time and what is the textLabel at that time. you should put print statement in `cellforrowatindexpath` also.